# Pygame object insatance not following physics

Tags: python, object, pygame, instance

I am doing a pygame problem for homework  where I must add two rectangles to a screen and having them bounce around and collide with one another. I havent even started the collision aspect because when I add the two rectangles only one of them starts moving.

```
import pygame
import sys
import random as rn

pygame.init()

BLACK = ( 0,0,0)
WHITE = (255,255,255)
BLUE =  (0,0,255)
RED =   (255,0,0)
YELLOW = (255,255,0)
num_of_rects = 2
colors = [BLACK, BLUE, RED, YELLOW]

def doRectsOverlap(rect1, rect2):
    for a,b in [(rect1,rect2),(rect2,rect1)]:
        if ((isPointInsideRect(a.left, a.top, b)) or (isPointInsideRect(a.left, a.bottom, b)) or (isPointInsideRect(a.right, a.top, b)) or (isPointInsideRect(a.right, a.bottom, b))):
            return True

    return False
def isPointInsideRect(x,y,rect):
    if (x > rect.left) and (x < rect.right) and (y > rect.top) and (y < rect.bottom):
        return True
    else:
        return False

class Rectangle:
    """
    Refer to the instructions if you need to modify this.
    """

    def __init__(self, color, loc):
        self.loc = loc
        self.color = color

    def my_draw(self,screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.loc)


    def my_move(self,xoffset,yoffset):
        self.loc = [self.loc[0]+xoffset,self.loc[1]+yoffset] + self.loc[2:]


size = [300, 300]   
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
pygame.display.set_caption("C200 CHANGE")

rects = []
for i in range(2):
    rects.append(Rectangle(rn.choice(colors), [rn.randint(0,200), rn.randint(0, 200), 20, 20]))




if __name__ == "__main__":
    xd = 2
    yd = 2
    while True:
        pygame.time.wait(40)

        for event in pygame.event.get(): 
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        screen.fill(WHITE)

        for r in rects:
            r.my_draw(screen)

        if r.loc[0] > 280:
            xd = -rn.randint(1,3)
        if r.loc[1] > 280:
            yd = -rn.randint(1,3)
        if r.loc[0] < 10:
            xd = rn.randint(1,3)
        if r.loc[1] < 10:
            yd = rn.randint(1,3)
        r.my_move(xd,yd)

        pygame.display.flip()
```

I found out that only the second instance of the rectangle class is the rectangle that moves. By adding a color list and assigning specific colors, for example the first rectangle was red the second was black and only the black one started moving.

Comment: My guess is that you want to put all those if-statements inside the for-loop. In other words, indent the if-statements.

Comment: I agree. It is just a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). The code which is expected to move the rectangles is executed once after the `for`-loop. So just the last rectangle in `rects` is moved. Put the code in the loop, to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It s a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). The `if` statement needs to be **in** the `for`-loop rather than **after** the `for`-loop:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    xd = 2
    yd = 2
    while True:
        pygame.time.wait(40)

        for event in pygame.event.get(): 
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: 
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        screen.fill(WHITE)

        for r in rects:
            r.my_draw(screen)

            #-->| INDENTATION

            if r.loc[0] > 280:
                xd = -rn.randint(1,3)
            if r.loc[1] > 280:
                yd = -rn.randint(1,3)
            if r.loc[0] < 10:
                xd = rn.randint(1,3)
            if r.loc[1] < 10:
                yd = rn.randint(1,3)
            r.my_move(xd,yd)

        pygame.display.flip()
```